# Discord.js GuildMember#roles appears to sometimes be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a function that accepts a user ID, and should return an array of all role IDs the user has, from all guilds that the bot is a part of.
To achieve this I wrote the following code

```js
async getRoleList(userId) {
    const guilds = this.client.guilds.cache.array();
    const guildRoles = [];
    const proms = guilds.map(async (guild) => {
        const member = await guild.members.fetch(userId).catch(() => {});
        if (!member) return;
        const roleCollection = member.roles.cache;
        guildRoles.push(roleCollection.array().map((role) => role.id));
    });
    await Promise.all(proms);
    const res = guildRoles.flat();
    res.push(userId);
    return res;
}
```

However, I have noticed that on occasion I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`
I am not able to replicate this bug reliably, it just seemingly randomly is thrown in production. From what I can tell of the discord.js docs the `roles` property of GuildMember always be there, and so I do not understand how the GuildMember exists but has no role manager.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your discord.js version with npm. This might have been fixed.

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1870

Comment: The project is recent (the issue you linked was posted in 2017 and fixed in early 2018), and the GuildMember object does exist. My issue is not with caching, I am explicitly fetching the member here. Also, the issue is not with the `GuildMember` object not existing, the issue is with the roles manager not existing of the GuildMember